# How to send array of data to controller with ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want send arrays of data to back-end at once but i can't.

## issue

1.
this is what i send currently

```
array:5 [
  "_token" => "S5s5ZTTnnP93MyXgCql0l9vhHsiqt5VWaFyEedXj"
  "product_id" => "21"
  "specification_id" => "6"
  "text_dec" => "1"
  "longtext_dec" => null
]
```

It should be like:

```
Array [
  0 = [
    data
  ]
  1 = [
    data
  ]
  2 = [
    data
  ]
]
```

2. I always get same `ID` as `specification_id` while each row in my blade has different `ID`

## Code

`appending script`

```
<script defer>
    $(document).ready(function() {
//select the category
        $('select[name="selectset"]').on('change', function() {
            var id = $(this).val();
            if(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ url('admin/selectset') }}/'+encodeURI(id),
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(result) {
//sort the results
                        result.sort(function(a,b) {
                            return (a.position > b.position) ? 1 : ((b.position > a.position) ? -1 : 0);
                        });


                        $.each(result, function(key1, value1) {

                            var vvvid = value1.id;

//textfield and textareafield are part of my issue (appended rows)
                            if(value1['type'] == 'textfield'){
                                var my_row = $('<div class="row mt-20 ccin">');
                                $('div#dataaa').append(my_row);
                            }else{
                                var my_row = $('<div class="row mt-20 ccin">');
                                $('div#dataaa').append(my_row);
                            }

                            // second data (get values)
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '{{ url('admin/findsubspecification') }}/'+value1['id'],
                                type: "GET",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success:function(data) {
                                    // Check result isnt empty
                                    var helpers = '';
                                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                        helpers += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.title+'</option>';
                                    });


//this is the part of my issue
                                    if(value1['type'] == 'textfield'){
                                        var my_html = '{{ Form::open() }}<input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}"><input name="specification_idd" class="specification_idd" id="specification_idd" type="hidden" value="'+vvvid+'"><div class="col-md-4">'+value1.title+'</div>';
                                        my_html += '<div class="col-md-6"><input id="text_decc" name="text_decc" placeholder="text field" class="text_decc form-control"></div>';
                                        my_html += '<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" id="custmodalsaveee" class="custmodalsaveee btn btn-xs btn-success">Save</button>{{Form::close()}}</div>';
                                        my_row.html(my_html);
                                    }else{ //second part of my issue
                                        var my_html = '{{ Form::open() }}<input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}"><input name="specification_idd" class="specification_idd" id="specification_idd" type="hidden" value="'+vvvid+'"><div class="col-md-4">'+value1.title+'</div>';
                                        my_html += '<div class="col-md-6"><textarea id="longtext_decc" name="longtext_decc" placeholder="text area field" class="longtext_decc form-control"></textarea></div>';
                                        my_html += '<div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" id="custmodalsaveee" class="custmodalsaveee btn btn-xs btn-success">Save</button>{{Form::close()}}</div>';
                                        my_row.html(my_html);
                                    }


                                }
                            });
                            // second data

                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

result of code above is like:

[image: one]

`saving script` **the part that should be fixed**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".custmodalsaveee", function(e){
        var id = $('input[name="product_id"]').val();

        $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "{{ url('admin/addnewcustomsubspecifications') }}",
          data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'product_id': id,
            'specification_id': $('.specification_idd').val(),
            'text_dec': $('.text_decc').val(),
            'longtext_dec': $('.longtext_decc').val(),
          },
          success: function (data) {
            alert('Specification added successfully in your product!');
          },
          error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error!', data);
          }
        });
  });
  });
</script>
```

`controller`

```
public function addnewcustomsubspecifications(Request $reqss){
        dd($reqss->all());

    //   $this->validate($reqss, array(
    //     'product_id' => 'required',
    //     'specification_id' => 'required',
    //     'text_dec' => 'nullable',
    //     'longtext_dec' => 'nullable',
    //   ));


    //   $add = CustomProductSpecification::create([
    //       'product_id' => $reqss->product_id,
    //       'specification_id' => $reqss->specification_id,
    //       'text_dec' => $reqss->text_dec,
    //       'longtext_dec' => $reqss->longtext_dec,
    //   ]);
    //   $parent = Specification::where('id', '=', $reqss->specification_id)->first();
    //   return response()->json(array('data'=>$add,'parent'=>$parent));
}
```

Any idea?

## Update

html output

[image: two]

## Update2

So based on suggestions i've used `.map()` here is my code and the results

`script`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".custmodalsaveee", function(e){
        var id = $('input[name="product_id"]').val();

        var specification_idd = $( ".ccin" ).map(function() {
            return $( this ).find('.specification_idd').val();
            return $( this ).find('.text_decc').val();
            return $( this ).find('.longtext_decc').val();
        }).get();
        var text_decc = $( ".ccin" ).map(function() {
            return $( this ).find('.text_decc').val();
        }).get();
        var longtext_decc = $( ".ccin" ).map(function() {
            return $( this ).find('.longtext_decc').val();
        }).get();
  console.log(specification_idd);
  console.log(text_decc);
  console.log(longtext_decc);

        $.ajax({
//rest of it as it was...
```

and the console results

[image: three]

## Question

1. How do i get related results together? `specification_id` and `text fields` as 1 array
2. how I avoid of empty values? **if `text_dec` and `longtext_dec` are empty for each `specification_id` doesn't need to be send** `example` specification 40 doesn't have any value in `longtext_dec` or `text_dec` no need to be send

Comment: Ok, so all related data is contained each within their own `div.row`, yes?  Then what you need to do is select the `div.row` and for each of them, build an object with their nested data, and all those objects will be put in an array that you send to the api.  You can look at https://api.jquery.com/map for some details about how you can do this.  And you will also need to be familiar with how to send json to an api, and how to make that api read in the json and parse it.

Comment: @Taplar yes. so i made something like `var ccin = $( ".ccin" ).map(function() {
            return $( this ).val();
        }).get();
  console.log(ccin);` and i got `(7) ["", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
0: ""
1: ""
2: ""
3: ""
4: ""
5: ""
6: ""
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: Right, because `this` is the ccin element.  You have to find the nested elements in the ccin (ex. `$(this).find('.specification_idd').val()`) and build the response object for them.

Comment: @Taplar for the val with `.find()` it is returning values now however it returns all values even those that i didn't fill their inputs, and about `product_id` as this function is in product edit page it doesn't matter much product id for all is the same.

Comment: @Taplar this is like 3rd question i'm making for this issue and you're the only one who actually knows about it, would you mind share an answer here so i can see your code? i really need to fix this :( `appreciate it`

Comment: I've changed it to class.

Comment: I've not written a full solution for this.  I'm providing you pointers for attempting to fix this yourself.  It is a better learning experience if you work through the issue yourself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2m7o3zqx/  Here is a small example of how map can be used to create the array of input values.

Comment: @Taplar thanks bro I updated my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180535/discussion-between-taplar-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 1):

Robert, you should directly return view from your Ajax call in your laravel method and just bind html response from the view with your new data.

That is pretty easy way of doing it.